# Php post http request using json

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to send this json object using the POST method but i'm not sure how to include the headers below, i was checking a lot of examples, but no one uses the headers below listed.

This is the code of my php processing page, this page will process the inputs received from a form.html and will create the json object to be transferred to the http server (external platform)

```
<?php 
$host ="10.10.237.8"; 
$puerto = 21098; 
$BUFF = 2048; 
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP); 
$conexion = socket_connect($socket, $host, $puerto); 
if($conexion) 
{ 
    $msisdn=$_POST["msisdn"]; 
    $mensaje=$_POST["mensaje"]; 
    $php_array = array( 
        "numero" => $msisdn, 
        "mensaje" => "$mensaje", 
    ); 
    $json_array=json_encode($php_array); 
    echo "Conexion Exitosa, puerto: " . $puerto."\n\n"; 
    echo $json_array; 
    socket_write($socket, $json_array); 
    // Receive the results (if any) from the server 
    $server_response = socket_read($socket, $BUFF); 
    $decoded_response = json_decode($server_response, true); // decode the data received 
    echo $decoded_response['passphrase']; // and spit the results 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "\nLa conexion TCP no se pudo realizar, puerto: ".$puerto; 
} 
socket_close($socket); 
?>
```

these are the headers information, where i whould include them ? how to do it ? using cURL ? do you have a good example ?

```
POST /SMBULK/BATCH HTTP/1.0
Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0
Host: 10.10.237.8:21098
Content-Length: 395
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (solaris2.10)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: */*
```

I hope you can help me. The php code above is not working because some of the information (POST, Content-Length, Content-Type, User-Agent...etc ) is not being included (except "host" which did was included).

I managed to did this but it's not working:

```
<?php
$str_obj_json='{
"method":"SUBMIT","params":{
"batchType":"submit",
"batchId":"alvarons",
"origAddr":"550",
"origTon":2,
"userData":"Movistar les desea Feliz Navidad",
"submits":
 [
  {
  "messId":"mess127_001",
  "destAddr":"51975375377"}
 ]
  }
}';
$ch = curl_init('http://10.10.237.8:21098/SMBULK/BATCH');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str_obj_json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Length: 395',
'Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0',
'User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (solaris2.10)',
'Connection: Keep-Alive',
'Accept: */*')
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: If you want to send a `HTTP/1.0` header, why are using sockets? Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) for basic examples using PHP cURL lib.

Comment: I'm new using this kind of things in php, do you have a good example of how to do it ?

Comment: This [post](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl) explains how can you send custom headers and data using post. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To send json object using cUrl you have to add "Content-Type: application/json" to header

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                array(
'Content-type: application/json'
'Content-Length: 395',
'Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0',
'User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (solaris2.10)',
'Connection: Keep-Alive',
'Accept: */*');
```